# Confusion related to Gaussian Markov Random field

Tags: normal-distribution, random-variable, markov-process, heteroscedasticity, gaussian-process

I was reading this [paper](http://www.nada.kth.se/kurser/kth/2d5342/kurspaket/aykroyd96bayesian.pdf) related to Gaussian Markov Random field. I didn't get how they derived this equation from the standard multivariate gaussian distribution equation

[image]

The multivariate gaussian distribution is given by

$P(X) = \frac{1}{{(2\pi)}^{N/2}|\Sigma|^{1/2}} exp^{-\frac{1}{2}x^T\Sigma^{-1}x}$.

I didn't get how they derived the above equation. Clarifications guys?